# VBA: Qualify Worksheets for dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel

I am just getting started with VBA.

I have a workbook containing many numbered sheets (1,2,3,4 etc).

I now have read that Qualifying a Worksheet as per below:

```
Dim 1 As Worksheet: Set 1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1")
```

then calling it as:

```
1.Range("B15").Value
```

is faster than activating it (as I have done) eg.

```
Worksheets(1).Activate
```

I would like though to access my sheets dynamically through a loop, as in:

```
Worksheets(i).Activate
```

Can this be done with the Qualifying method?  I'm stuck.

Comment: Worksheets already have a number. The problem is 'activate'

Comment: `Dim 1 As Worksheet` is [not a valid statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/visual-basic-naming-rules), and `1.Range("B15")` is not a valid statement either because `Worksheet` **`CodeNames`** cannot be numbers (_"Not a legal object name"_). You have to use `Worksheets(i & "")` (String), or `Worksheets(i)` (Index) - The **`Index`** method is faster

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a number as a variable name. You can loop through the worksheets collection in two ways - the first is marginally more efficient I believe but doubt you'll notice the difference.

As you say there is rarely any need to actually activate a sheet.

```
Sub x()

Dim ws As Worksheet, i As Long

'option 1
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Activate
    ws.Range("A1") = 1 'no need to activate first
Next ws

'option 2
For i = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Worksheets(i).Activate
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: hi, thanks.  The numbers are the names of the individual worksheets.  They are created dynamically so my workbook could have fpr example 100 worksheets named 1,2,3,4...100

Comment: To be honest I don't really know what quesion you're asking. I've outlined the basic approach to looping through worksheets - hopefully you can build on it for your particular task or ask a specific question.

Comment: Thanks ... I will keep working on it given your feedback.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Worksheets have an Index which is the order they are currently in within the workbook. So the leftmost worksheet is Worksheet(1). This is not necessarily the same as the name of the e.g. Worksheet("Sheet1") or Worksheet("1").

Say I have sheets "2" ,"1", "3", in that order in the workbook:

1. Sheet 2 A1 has "First sheet named "2" "
2. Sheet 1 A1 has "Second Sheet named "1" "
3. Sheet 3 A1 has "Third sheet named "3" "

Then run the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    Dim arr(), i As Long
    arr = Array("1", "2", "3") '<== Sheet names

    Debug.Print "Looping by name: "
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)           '<== Looping by name
        Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(arr(i)).Range("A1").Value
    Next i

    Debug.Print String(40, Chr$(61))
    Debug.Print vbNewLine
    Debug.Print "Looping by sheet index: "

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count   '<== Looping by index (order from left to right)
        Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("A1").Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

You get:

[image: Output]

Note: You can also `For Each` over the Worksheet collection which will loop in the same order as by Index skipping any Chart sheet objects.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is simple:

1) When you pass string (say, "1"), you're referring to sheet's name

2) When you pass number (say, 1), you're referring to position in sheets' collection.

The important thing is to understand **what is *sheets' collection***.

There are several types of sheets: worksheet, chart sheet, dialog sheet (also two types of macro sheets; you can see all five of them via `right-click sheet's tab -> Insert`). So, it is very important to understand *which* collection to use.

Say, you have four sheets (from left to right):

1. Dialog sheet (name "dialog1")
2. Worksheet (name "sheet1")
3. Chart sheet (name "chart1")
4. Worksheet (name "sheet2")

So, **all** sheets can be enumerated through `Sheets` collection. Thus:

1. `Sheets(1)` returns "dialog1" dialog sheet
2. `Sheets(2)` returns "sheet1" worksheet
3. `Sheets(3)` returns "chart1" chart sheet
4. `Sheets(4)` returns "sheet2" worksheet

If you need the collection of only chart sheets, you use `Charts` collection. In our case Charts(1) will return "chart1" chart sheet.

If you need the collection of only worksheets, you use `Worksheets` collection. In our case `Worksheets(2)` will return "sheet2" worksheet.

The same goes for dialog sheets - use `DialogSheets` collection (although it's not visible in IntelliSense, you can see it: `F2 -> Right-click -> Show Hidden Members`).

And last but not the least, every sheet has `Index` property. But be careful with it since it returns the value of index in `Sheets` collection. This means that in our case `Worksheets(2).Index` will return 4.