# Using variable sheetname in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a novice at VBA (just starting to learn). In my userform I have a combobox with values from 1 to 12(not string) representing the months. I want the user to pick a month and based on that, the multiple listboxes and labels I have placed should get filled by the relevant values in one of the 12 sheets representing each month. as I am a novice I have a lot of problems here but for starters the following lines do not seem to work on userform_initiate()

```
For j = 0 To 1
    arr_trh(0, j) = Sheets("Sheet6").Cells(4, j + 1)
Next j
```

I can get it to work for a single sheet by using

```
arr_trh(0, j) = Sheet6.Cells(4, j + 1)
```

However, what I'm trying to do later on is to create a string and somehow concatenate "Sheet" and combobox value to pass on to Sheets() function.

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: "the following lines do not seem to work" -- that isn't a very helpful problem statement. Are you getting an error message? If so -- what? On what line?

Comment: A userform and a worksheet are not the same thing.I think you're working with worksheets, so avoid any instruction that has to do with userforms for now. The worksheet is the spreadsheet, with tabs at the bottom; user forms are custom form elements designed in the Visual Basic Editor.   A Google search will explain better.

Comment: What about `Sheets("Sheet" & x).Cells()`? Where x is `string` type variable and `x` gets value from combobox.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than referring to the `Sheet` object like:

```
v = Sheet1.Range("A1")
```

use:

```
v = Sheets(1).Range("A1")
```

which you can index like:

```
v = Sheets(i).Range("A1")
```

where `i` is a variable.

Comment: Excellent! that seems to have worked, I had no idea you could use it like that. Thanks John and Ashlee for the answers as well. Now to see if I can assign combobox selection to it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, my [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50305236/vba-qualify-worksheets-for-dynamic-range/50309167#50309167) answer will help you to figure out how to refer to sheets. Also, it tells about caveats of `Index` property.

Comment: That was an excellent post and it helped me figurd out what's going on a lot. Thanks!