# VBA Excel select & delete all shapes with the same ID and remove

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete all the shapes from my sheet. They have the same ID.

[image]

I found two codes:

The first one:

```
Public Sub ActiveShapes()
    Dim ShpObject As Variant

    If TypeName(Application.Selection) = "Firestop" Then
        Set ShpObject = Application.Selection
        ShpObject.Delete
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

is not working. There are no errors, but also no reaction at all.

The second one:
[Selecting a shape in Excel with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157421/selecting-a-shape-in-excel-with-vba)

```
 Sub Firestopshapes()
     ActiveSheet.Shapes("Firestop").Delete
 End Sub
```

works, but remove only one by one element. In my event, all the elements have the "Firestop" ID. I would like to make them all deleted at once. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is thet `If TypeName(Application.Selection) = "Firestop" Then` is never true. Have a look into the [TypeName function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/typename-function) does not return the **name** of the `Application.Selection` but instead it returs what **type** `Application.Selection` is. Here it probably returns `Object` because a shape is an object.

Actually names are unique. You cannot add 2 shapes with the same name. That is why `ActiveSheet.Shapes("Firestop").Delete` only deletes one shape.

There seems to be a bug that when you copy a named shape 2 shapes with the same name exist (which should not be possible). You can get around this by deleting that shape in a loop until you get an error (no shape with that name is left).

```
On Error Resume Next
Do
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Firestop").Delete
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Do
Loop
On Error GoTo 0 'don't forget this statement after the loop
```

Comment: Hi, 
Previously I used:
ActiveSheet.Range("D24").PasteSpecial
        Selection.Name = "Firestop"
what made the "Firestop" ID for all of them. This is why i don't have unique ID anymore.

Comment: @MariuszKrukar yep, this bug is still not fixed. Have a look at my edited answer. You can use that workaround.

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to use `On Error Resume Next` often. We recommend using it only when it is indispensable.

```
Sub test()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each shp In Ws.Shapes
        If shp.Name = "Firestop" Then
            shp.Delete
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: While you are correct in general, if there are more shapes with other names than `Firestop` then the `On Error Resume Next` approach could still be faster. Depends on the ratio `Firestop` vs `other names`. Anyway you get my vote.

Comment: Have a look, I improved my answer by kicking the `On Error …` outside the loop, so we use it only once :) Now this will definitly be faster than looping through all shapes.

Comment: **Just for the fun of it**  @Pᴇʜ: Both methods are fast. In my testing, Dy.Lees method however is approximately 1 microsecond faster. :P May vary under different tests. I tested both the codes on a worksheet which had `717` shapes. where `229` shapes had the same name. used [THIS](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1068) to mesaure the time. Let me know if you both get different results... BTW Upvoted both answers... Good work!

Comment: @SiddharthRout, Good job.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Just because of curiosity I did some tests: 1000 different shapes + 5 shapes named `AAA`. My code `3,68E-02` dy.lee's `4,85E-02`. Best case  (1000 shapes, no `AAA` so nothing to delete) me `5,91E-03` (note **E-03**) and dy.lee `4,51E-02`. Worst case (1000 shapes `AAA`, all to delete): me `0,65` and dy.lee `0,59`. • So exactly what I guessed ^^. If there are a lot of unique shapes and only few duplicate names mine is a bit faster (well less than I actually assumed I must say). Dy.Lee's is faster if there are a lot of duplicates and very less uniques. Actually both are flash fast.

Comment: nice testing @Pᴇʜ :)