# VBA Excel remove shapes from more than one sheet at once

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to make the all specified shapes gone from more than 1 sheet. It applies roughly to the "Cables" sheets.
It's related with my previous query:

[VBA Excel select & delete all shapes with the same ID and remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60433388/vba-excel-select-delete-all-shapes-with-the-same-id-and-remove/60433980#60433980)

According to my query regarding the PDF saving

[VBA excel excluding specified sheets when saving the .PDF version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60113472/vba-excel-excluding-specified-sheets-when-saving-the-pdf-version)

I prepared the code, which looks as follows:

```
 Sub Firestopshapes()
 Dim shp As Shape
   Dim Ws As Worksheet

  If Ws.Name Like "*Cables*" Then
  'Set Ws = ActiveSheet

  For Each shp In Ws.Shapes
    If shp.Name = "Firestop" Then
        shp.Delete
    End If
  Next shp
 End If
End Sub
```

Unfortunately I am getting error:

**Object variable or With block variable not set**

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: `For Each Ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets`.

Comment: Side note - please use the "excel" and "vba" tags instead of "excel-vba."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To close this question out... you forgot the loop through all the worksheets:

```
For Each Ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Ws.Name Like "*Cables*" Then
        ...
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub Firestopshapes()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    For Each Ws In Sheets
      If InStr(Ws.Name, "Cables") > 0 And Ws.Shapes.Count > 0 Then
            For Each shp In Ws.Shapes
              If shp.Name = "Firestop" Then
                  shp.Delete
                End If
            Next shp
        End If
    Next Ws
End Sub
```